# в данном коде в методе "Get pictures" recycler view == null, подскажите плиз, вобще не могу понять в чем причина

Tags: android

```
public class PictureFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<Picture> pictures;
public static final String URL_TYPE_FOR_TOP_PICTURES = "top";
public static final String URL_TYPE_FOR_NEW_PICTURES = "new";
private ArrayList<String> urls;
private PictureFragmentPresenter pictureFragmentPresenter;
public Context context;
private View rootView;


public PictureFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment PictureFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static PictureFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    PictureFragment fragment = new PictureFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pictures = new ArrayList<>();
    urls = new ArrayList<>();
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_picture, container, false);
    initViews();
    pictureFragmentPresenter = new PictureFragmentPresenter();
    return rootView;
}

private void initViews() {
    Button btnNew = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_new);
    btnNew.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btnTop = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_top);
    btnTop.setOnClickListener(this);
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_for_pictures);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String urlType;
    if (!pictureFragmentPresenter.checkAccesToInternet(getActivity())) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.internet_not_available), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_new:
            urlType = URL_TYPE_FOR_NEW_PICTURES;
            pictureFragmentPresenter.getPicturesFromApi(urlType, getActivity());
            break;
        case R.id.btn_top:
            urlType = URL_TYPE_FOR_TOP_PICTURES;
            pictureFragmentPresenter.getPicturesFromApi(urlType, getActivity());
            break;
    }
}


public void getPictures(ArrayList<Picture> pictures) {
    PicturesAdapter picturesAdapter = new PicturesAdapter(getActivity(), pictures);
    for (int i = 0; i < pictures.size(); i++) {
        Log.v("tag", "PICTURE URL = " + pictures.get(i).getUrl());
    }
    if (recyclerView != null) {   //ЕСЛИ УБРАТЬ ЭТО УСЛОВИЕ, ТО КРЕШИТ
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(picturesAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    }
  }


}
```

Comment: А где этот метод `getPictures` вызывается-то?

Comment: я получается пробрасую из модели в PictureFragmentPresenter
и отсюда возвращаю в фрагмент, и уже с фрагмента хочу запустить ресайклвью..

public class PictureFragmentPresenter { 
  public PictureFragment getFragmentInstance() {
        return new PictureFragment();
    }

    public void returnPictures(ArrayList<Picture> pictures) {
        getFragmentInstance().getPictures(pictures);
    }
}

Comment: Получается вы создали фрагмент, но нигде его не отобразили (не добавили его во фрагмент менеджер). Соответственно никакие методы жизненного цикла у него не отработали и вью не инициализировались. Поэтому ресайклер null.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `context` в `new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);` не инициализирован, по моему. Попробуйте присвоить этой ссылке, к примеру, `getApplicationContext()` или `getActivity()`.